# How do you grab certain values from different columns in a dataframe when applying column-wide functions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is to be grouped on a column with categorical values.

`A,B,start,end
pineapple,4,2:00,3:00
pineapple,2,2:30,3:50
pineapple,8,3:30,3:40
apple,3,1:20,4:30
apple,5,1:30,4:30
...`

I want a dataframe that looks like this..

`A,B,start,end
pineapple,6,2:00,3:50
apple,8,1:20,4:30
...`

Where the start and end times take on the extremes of those in its grouping...
How can I accomplish this without iterating through each row to keep track of min_time and max_time within each grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by `dict`:

```
df = df.groupby('A', sort=False).agg({'B':'sum', 'start':'min', 'end':'max'})
print (df)
            end start   B
A                        
pineapple  3:50  2:00  14
apple      4:30  1:20   8
```